# SQL - How to form a string by concatenating semicolons to a number?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

Specifically MySQL, but I'm guessing the answer should be generic.

First I'm setting a variable as a number like so:

```
SET @somenumber:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Note that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is basically MySQL's equivalent of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Next I try to create a string by concatenating semicolons onto this number:

```
SET @somestring:=';'+@somenumber+';';
```

Last I try to insert this as a string:

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` (`somevarcharcolumn`) VALUES (somestring);
```

And the result is that only the number is added in the column and the semicolons are missing.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to make it work? Thank you much!

Comment: Isn't `+` the addition operator? For string concatenation use the `CONCAT` function

Comment: Read the manual for `CONCAT_WS`

Comment: Yes, it is the addition operator. I was reading a source suggesting it was also used for concatenation. Thank you much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
//MySQL
SET @somestring:=CONCAT(';',@somenumber,';');

//SQL Server
SET @somestring = ';'+CAST(@somenumber AS VARCHAR)+';';

//Oracle
SET somestring_ :=';' || somenumber_ || ';';
```